# How to properly compare dates in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle, date

I have the following code and I can't get it to work due to datatype issues. I tried tweaking it around multiple times but I keep getting errors such as

> An exception occurred filling the dataset:
>   ERROR [07001] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Classic ASP Page:

```
MyBool = MyProject.MyMethod(Request("ToDate")) //for example:"7/18/2017"
```

My Class:

```
public bool MyMethod(string EndDate)
    {
        MyData data = new MyData();
        return (data.MyMethod(EndDate));
    }
public bool MyMethod(string EndDate)
    {
(...)
CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Cast(StartDate as date) <= Cast(@EndDate as date)");
AddInParameter("EndDate", DbType.String, EndDate);
```

My Table:

```sql
STARTDATE [VARCHAR2(10) NULL]
```

I would appreciate any advice on how the datatypes should be handled in this case and/or the SQL command modified.

This is what gets executed in AddInParameter():

```
DbParameter parameter = providerFactory.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = FormatParameterName("EndDate"); 
parameter.DbType = type; //(DbType type = String)
parameter.Value = value; //(Object value = "7/18/2017")
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Can you show your exact code - looking at what you have presented that would not even compile.

Comment: Use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) to convert the value on the server, and `DateTime.Parse` to convert the value on the client side.

Comment: @stuartd - I've been trying to keep my date parameter as string and tried TO_DATE within my SQL command, but I constantly keep getting the same error I mentioned before. This is the last option I tested:

    (TO_DATE(StartDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(@EndDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @PaulF - I did correct some typos in CreateCommand line. The code compiles, I just removed irrelevant code.

Comment: The error message seems to be suggesting that no parameter value was found for Enddate. Can you show the code in `AddInParameter`?

Comment: This is what gets executed in AddInParameter():

    DbParameter parameter = providerFactory.CreateParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = FormatParameterName("EndDate");
    parameter.DbType = type; //(DbType type = String)
    parameter.Value = value; //(Object value = "7/18/2017")
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

Comment: I have moved your comment to the question - it looks like you comment out setting a value for the parameter.

Comment: No, this is not really a case. "parameter.Value = value;" is a new line, so it is not a part of my comment (which I added for simplicity). I corrected the question.

Comment: It is always best to add the code to the original question - to get it formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

If your StartDate and EndDate column is of character type, change it to DateTime. Character typed columns such as varchar, nvarchar etc. are for characters, datetime typed columns are for DateTime's.

There is no point in saving your DateTime's as a string.

As a side note; in a DateTime in C# doesn't have any implicit format. It just a value that contains pieces of times. String representation of this has **formats**.

What you need to do if you want to keep your column type as it is, is something like this: `EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Displays 08/04/0070 A.D.`

Comment: Ofcause it's an answer to the question @Stuartd!! The solution is in the example code for what peter asked...

Comment: Does Oracle require dates in the format `08/04/0070 A.D.` now?

Comment: This is the logic handled by C# @Stuartd, if he wants to suit oracle then he can consult the date documentation for oracle, and that was definitely not part of this question.

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle, the error message is an Oracle message - I'd say that was part of the question.

Comment: No, it might be tagged with oracle as well, but the code he gave as an example is in C# as it is also tagged as a C# question.

Comment: @Sizons - I cannot make any modifications to column character types, so I need to focus on my SQL command and code (rather the SQL command, which still does not seem to match my datatypes). Sorry if the question has not been tagged properly or has any unclear message.

Comment: All you need to do to make sure this always works is to always format your string in the same way as the format you use to test the condition in your code. So using the string.format function you can find one that will work during the runtime, Oracle should not care what the format is because it is in varchar format in the db. Seems like simple logic to me?

Comment: I am doing comparison within my SQL WHERE clause, not my C#/VBScript code. At this point, it is does not seem that simple to me :(.

Comment: so if you add parameter.Value = value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); are you saying you still get the same error with values input using such formatting of the input?